Assuming $\arg b \equiv 2\arg a \pmod{2\pi}$ and $|b|=1,|a|\leq 2$ , prove that $|z_1|=|z_2|=1$
Let $z_1,z_2$ solutions of $z^2-az+b=0$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{C}^*$
Suppose that $\arg b \equiv 2\arg a \pmod{2\pi}$ and $|b|=1,|a|\leq 2$
Prove that $|z_1|=|z_2|=1$
I can't find any way to do it
I think about geometry
Using the angle bisector theorem we can find that the lenght
$AB=\frac{AX}{OX}$
where $X$ is the intersection of $AB$ with the x-axis
It seems useful but I don't know how to complete

Write $a$ in polar form as $re^{i\theta}$ where $0\le r\le2$. Let $w=ze^{-i\theta}$. The equation can be rewritten as $w^2-rw+1=0$. Since this is a quadratic equation with constant term $1$, real coefficients and discriminant $r^2-4\le0$, we have $w_1w_2=1$ and $w_1=w_2^\ast$. Hence $|z_1|=|w_1|=\sqrt{w_1w_1^\ast}=\sqrt{w_1w_2}=1$ and similarly for $|z_2|$.

We're given information about the arguments and magnitudes of the numbers, so what immediately comes to mind is solving this problem using polar coordinates. Let $a=ke^{i\theta}$ for $0\leq k\leq 2$ and $b=e^{2i\theta}$.
From the quadratic formula, the solutions to $z^2-az+b=0$ are:
$$z=\frac{ke^{i\theta}\pm\sqrt{k^2e^{2i\theta}-4e^{2i\theta}}}{2}=e^{i\theta}\frac{k\pm i\sqrt{4-k^2}}{2}.$$
So, we have $|z|=|e^{i\theta}|\left|\frac{k\pm i\sqrt{4-k^2}}{2}\right|=\frac{k^2}{4}+\frac{4-k^2}{4}=1$.

Is it possible to solve it with geo (angle bisector theorem) , if it's can you explain how
